# How to print a multidimensional array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

```java
int arr[][] = new int[2][];
```

I am a beginner in Java and I couldn't understand why this is valid while we initialize a multidimensional array in Java. And I was trying to print a multidimensional array using

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

and I couldn't see values; instead what it prints was object's address.

Comment: What is printed is not the memory address, but the hash of the object in hex format, see [the `Object::toString` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()). As to the initialization: If one initializes a multidimensional array, one only has to define outermost dimension. One should remember that a multidimensional array is just an array of arrays. Thus each inner array can have a different size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int arr[][] = new int[2][];` creates an array of two one-dimensional arrays, where each one can have an arbitrary length. Only the first dimension needs to be specified for multidimensional array initializations.

You can use [`Arrays.deepToString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) to print the elements of a multidimensional array.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

The declaration is valid because `int[][]` is an array of arrays. So `int[x]` is an array itself. And if you declare `int[2][]` you can have up to 2 array inside that array but you don't specify the size of the inner arrays.

That's also the reason why `Arrays#toString()` is not working. Because you just `#toString` the inner arrays.

Answer (score 1):

To understand why this works properly

```
int arr[][] = new int[2][];
```

We need to know what are **Jagged arrays** in Java

`Jagged array is array of arrays such that member arrays can be of different sizes`

```
int[][] arr = new int[2][];

// row 0 gets 5 columns
arr[0] = new int[5];
// row 1 gets 11 columns
arr[1] = new int[11];
```

So to create an array we just need to pass the number of rows since number of columns can be variable

How do you traverse a Jagged Array

```
int a[][] = new int[2][];
a[0] = new int[2];
a[1] = new int[1];

a[0][0] = 1;
a[0][1] = 2;
a[1][0] = 3;

for(int i[]: a) {
    for(int j: i) {
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```